# Derby, SQL and CSV

Tags: java, sql, csv, derby

Bear in mind that this is a pretty greenhorn-question, so please, be patient with me.

So as a person who knows little to nothing about databases, undesirable conditions have lead me into a situation where I am to perform a task I know little about how to do.

In my hour of need, I come to you guys/gals.

Firstly, my task requires me to use Apache Derby to achieve the desired goals alongside Eclipse.

I've been given a single database located at `res/myCSVFile.csv`.

The text file with the `CSV` extension looks like this:

```
letter,name
A,alpha-static
B,beta-static
C,charlie-static
```

Doesn't look too threatening, right?

I know I can build a nice `HashMap` out of my `CSV` file like this:

```
Map<String, myFileType> myHashMap = new HashMap<>();
try(CSVReader rdr = new CSVReader(new FileReader("res/myCSVFile.csv"), ',','"',1)){
    for(String[] row : rdr.readAll()){
        File imagefile = new File(row[1]);
        myHashMap.put(row[0], new myFileType(imagefile, Integer.parseInt(row[2])));
    }
}
```

I know `CSV` separates columns by commas, so I assume what I see in this file are two columns, one labeled "letter" with the values "A", "B" and "C" under it, and another labeled "name" with "alpha-static", "beta-static" and "charlie-static" under it.

My situation requires me to use Derby to manipulate the above data as an `SQL` database. Knowing full well that a `CSV` file looks nothing like a `SQL` file, I know there is some conversion involved.

I don't know if Java can (or should) do this for me somehow, but I assume not.

Now, I do presume the `SQL` variant of my `CSV` file would look something like:

```
DROP TABLE possibleSqlTable;
CREATE TABLE possibleSqlTable(
  letter VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, name VARCHAR(14)
);
INSERT INTO possibleSqlTable(letter,name) VALUES ('A','alpha-static');
INSERT INTO possibleSqlTable(letter,name) VALUES ('B','beta-static');
INSERT INTO possibleSqlTable(letter,name) VALUES ('C','charlie-static');
```

That's just my guess in the dark at how this `SQL` database would look (correct me if I'm wrong). Assume that's saved as `res/possibleSqlDatabase.sql`.

Now, how do I get Derby in on the action?

Assuming my `SQL` database is correct as I've guessed above, how do I for example query a statement?

How would I, for example, map "A" to "alpha-static"? Can I do this with a simple `HashMap`? I'd love to see how, if that'd be possible.

I do have a basic, VERY basic, understanding of how `SQL`-commands work, but I would love some examples using my database.

When answering, just treat me like a preschooler trying to learn this stuff. I really am that new.

Comment: Not question related, you don't have put these `EDIT`s in the question body - there's a place for them called Edit Summary.

Comment: Oh. Must have overlooked that. Pardon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

In this case I create a local Database `/tmp/test`. 
**Attention**: If you want to use Derby as a service, you have to change the URL in `getConnection()` and start the database by yourself. You also can change the filename of the database at the same position.

The example can read the whole data with `getData()` or a single value with `getOneName(String)`.

In the constructor we create and fill the database (if necessary), read the whole data, read a single letter and read a non exististing letter.

Hope that helps

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class TestApp {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        TestApp myTestApp = new TestApp();
    }

    public TestApp() throws SQLException {
        this.createAndFillDatabase();
        Map<String, String> allData = this.getData();
        String oneData = this.getOneName("A");
        String noData = this.getOneName("D");
        System.out.println("allData = " + allData);
        System.out.println("oData   = " + oneData);
        System.out.println("noData  = " + noData);
    }

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:/tmp/test;create=true");
    }

    private void createAndFillDatabase() throws SQLException {
        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            ResultSet tables = conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "POSSIBLESQLTABLE", null);
            if (!tables.next()) {
                // create table
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE possibleSqlTable(\n"
                        + "  letter VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY\n"
                        + ", name VARCHAR(14)\n"
                        + ")");
                // insert data
                String[][] data = {{"A", "alpha-static"}, {"B", "beta-static"}, {"C", "charlie-static"}};
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO possibleSqlTable(letter,name) VALUES (?,?)");
                for (String[] row : data) {
                    pstmt.setString(1, row[0]);
                    pstmt.setString(2, row[1]);
                    pstmt.execute();
                }
                conn.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    private Map<String, String> getData() throws SQLException {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from possibleSqlTable");
            while (results.next()) {
                result.put(results.getString("letter"), results.getString("name"));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String getOneName(String letter) throws SQLException {
        String result = null;
        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from possibleSqlTable where letter = ?");
            pstmt.setString(1, letter);
            ResultSet results = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (results.next()) {
                result = results.getString("name");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I must say! Really good stuff. But I do get an error, and I do wonder if you could update your answer until I manage to get it working, so I can hand you the nice shiny "Accept answer". When I run it, I get a `No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:/tmp/test;create=true`-error from line 29. I don't really understand what I should change it to. I do have derby in my build path, if that matters. I'm also a little confused about where the `mySQLFile.sql` should be located, in order to function with your example? Help me understand this and I will be forever in your debt, friend!

Comment: Or is `mySQLFile.sql` not needed in your example? Forgive me for being a little slow. Beer's on me if you manage to help me solve my dilemma.

Comment: The driver must be in the classpath. You can call `java -cp .;derby.jar TestApp` inside your class output folder. There is no `mySQLFile.sql` in my example. You can find all SQL staements in the method `createAndFillDatabase`.

Comment: I added the line `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();` which seems to have solved it. It now prints out 

`allData = {A=alpha-static, B=beta-static, C=charlie-static}
oData   = alpha-static
noData  = null`

Is it suppose to say that?

I will look further into it to make sure I understand what this means exactly (feel free to educate me!), but there's no doubt you earned my "Accepted answer"!

Comment: The output is only an example, how to use the database. You can remove it. `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver")` is unnecessary with JDBC 4 (since JDK 6). The Derby JDBC Driver support it since version 10.2.2.0. But it doesn't matter if you call it.